# Derivation of Lagrangian dual problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

I am new to Lagrangians, and I am not sure if what I am doing is correct. The original problem was to find $\min\limits_{\theta}-log(\theta(1-\theta)^2), .5 \leq \theta \leq 1$, write the Lagrangian, and to derive the dual problem. My solution is $\theta = 0.5$.

My Lagrangian is $\mathcal{L}(\theta, \lambda) = -log(\theta(1-\theta)^2) - \lambda(\theta-0.5)$, $\lambda \geq 0$.

I constructed the dual function $g(\lambda) = \min\limits_{\theta} \mathcal{L}(\theta, \lambda) = \min\limits_{\theta} -log(\theta(1-\theta)^2) - \lambda(\theta-0.5), \lambda \geq 0$. My solution is $\theta = 0.5, \lambda = 2$.

I am not completely sure if my work is correct, and I am not sure how to construct the dual problem. My best attempt is $d^* = \max\limits_{\lambda \geq 0} g(\lambda) $

---

Is my work correct? How do you express the dual problem?

Comment: Where is the part in Lagrangian function for constraint $\theta \leq 1$? And Since this is a  problem with inequality constraints, may compute the KKT conditions.

Comment: @Ze-NanLi Is the constraint for $\theta$ supposed to be included in the Lagrangian? For this problem, I thought it wasn't relevant since it was just a characteristic of the value they wanted us to find... Also, I am not sure what the KKT conditions are, and how to compute that...

Comment: Of course you can write a partial Lagrangian function. And for KKT conditions you can refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions)